# Flask: files in static folder can not be reached (404)

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, static-files

I want to serve a react app with flask, but the "static_folder" does not seem to work. This is my very minimal code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="react_app/build")
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return app.send_static_file("index.html")

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the browser I can reach *http://localhost:5000* and it returns me the correct index.html. But all the static files like css and js files return a 404 error. For example there is a file: *react_app/build/bundle.css* or *react_app/build/js/some_name.js*. But typing *http://localhost:5000/bundle.css* or *http://localhost:5000/js/some_name.js* both return a 404 not found error.

From what I understand, if I specify a static_folder I should reach all files from that folder from the root url. What am I missing / missunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not what [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/) says:

> - **static_url_path** – can be used to specify a different path for the static files on the web. Defaults to the name of the *static_folder* folder.
> - **static_folder** – the folder with static files that should be served at static_url_path. Defaults to the 'static' folder in the root path of the application.

So, your files would be served at localhost:5000/react_app/build. Since that's probably not what you want, you should pass `static_url_path` as well, with a value of something like "static", so that you can find the files at localhost:5000/static.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add an important point. Do not forget to add  **static_url_path=''** because it removes any preceding path from the URL (i.e. the default /static).I am not seeing this in you code snippet.

For example,

```
 app = Flask (__name__,
            static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='web/static',
            template_folder='web/templates')
```

- **static_url_path**='' removes any preceding path from the URL (i.e. the
  default /static).
- **static_folder**='web/static' to serve any files found
  in the folder web/static as static files.
- **template_folder**='web/templates' similarly, this changes the templates
  folder.

Comment: This preceding path is so annoying, cost me so much time to fix it