# Adapting the forwarding to Flask application with routes and static files with the Apache 2

Tags: python, flask, apache2, proxypass, gssapi

There is a Flask Application running on the http://servername.com:5000/. It encapsulates some Bootstrap and static files provided in `gis_webapp/static/...` which works the way it should.

This is the tree of the project:

```
gis_webapp
├── __init__.py
├── routes.py
├── gunicorn_gis_webapp_conf.py
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap-4.6.0-dist
│   │   ├── css
│   │   └── js
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── img
│       ├── favicon.png
│       └── glogo.gif
└── templates
    ├── about.html
    ├── base.html
    ├── contact.html
    ├── errors
    │   └── 404.html
    ├── index.html
    └── result.html
```

As soon as I apply the forwarding through the Apache2 with the `mod_auth_gssapi` that runs on the same server via http://servername.com/ (http://servername.com:80/) using the http://servername.com/gis/ that has to inherit the whole content of the http://servername.com:5000/, **the following things stop to work:**

1. Communication between routes

   When I click on the *contact* link in the navigation bar it brings me to http://servername.com/contact/ (which does not exist) instead of http://servername.com/gis/contact
2. The content from the `/static` folder
3. Bootstrap from the `gis_webapp/static/bootstrap-4.6.0-dist` folder

What am I doing wrong?

The content of the `.conf` file is the following:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /gis/>
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:5000/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:5000/"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have found some suggestion in these threads and tried to apply the suggestions:

- [Link to Flask static files with url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for)

  ```css
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-4.6.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  ```
- [Using root_path argument in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533245/using-root-path-argument-in-flask)

  ```py
  gis_webapp = Flask(__name__, root_path=os.getcwd())
  ```
- [Link stylesheet from a parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216705/link-stylesheet-from-a-parent-folder)

  ```css
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../static/img/favicon.png">
  ```
- [Flask: files in static folder can not be reached (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591749/flask-files-in-static-folder-can-not-be-reached-404?rq=1)

  ```py
  gis_webapp = Flask(__name__,
               static_url_path='',
               static_folder='static',
               template_folder='templates')
  ```

Unfortunately they don't solve my issue.

I also tried to modify the paths in my `routes.py` file.

```py
# main page
@gis_webapp.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@gis_webapp.route("/index", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title="GIS")
```

was rewritten as:

```py
# main page
@gis_webapp.route("/gis/", methods=["GET"])
@gis_webapp.route("/gis/index", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title="GIS")
```

I also found this thread [Serving static files through apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739925/serving-static-files-through-apache) that suggest to apply the `ALIAS`, however it is not a solution for me, because later Apache2 and Flask Application gonna be on different servers. However, there is an opinion: *that the statics need to be distributed by the Apache, even if you then spread it across different servers, then it is better to mount the statics to where the Apache is.*

---

Till now I could partially solve the **2.** and **3.** issues with adjustments done in 'base.html', so this reference:

```css
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/img/favicon.png">
```

was changed to:

```css
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/gis/static/img/favicon.png">
```

So, afterwards I could see the content of the `/static` folder on the http://servername.com/gis/ page but it disappears when I open it though http://servername.com:5000/ ... do not understand why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to deploy the `SCRIPT_NAME` variable and [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) as suggested in [this article](https://dlukes.github.io/flask-wsgi-url-prefix.html):

```py
SCRIPT_NAME="/gis" gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 gis_webapp:gis_webapp
```

After that I was able to access the application via http://servername.com/gis/

However the initial URL http://servername.com:5000/ was yielding the `Internal Server Error`. To overcome it, simply use the http://servername.com:5000/gis/.